# Flutter - Send message to new WhatsApp Group

Tags: flutter

I am using this method to open a WhatsApp message in my app.

```
whatsapp() async{
  var contact = "+972528990525";
  var androidUrl = "whatsapp://send?phone=$contact&text=Hi, I need some help";
  var iosUrl = "https://wa.me/$contact?text=${Uri.parse('Hi, I need some help')}";

  try{
    if(Platform.isIOS){
      await launchUrl(Uri.parse(iosUrl));
    }
    else{
      await launchUrl(Uri.parse(androidUrl));
    }
  } on Exception{
    EasyLoading.showError('WhatsApp is not installed.');
  }
}
```

However, I need that the message be sent to two whatsapp numbers. Meaning, I want whatsapp to open a new group with two saved numbers from the app.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

The Whatsapp API does not offer any official API for creating a group or even sending messages to an existing group.

The only feature available is the one you are already using, "Click to chat" and you can see its documentation [here](https://faq.whatsapp.com/5913398998672934).

There are a few unofficial API's, from third parties, some of which you will have to pay to use, that offer this functionality.
However, since they are unofficial, you cannot guarantee they follow the Whatsapp terms of service or how long they will be supported and maintained.

For these reasons I won't link any workaround API here. They can be looked up and found online at your own risk.